# Creating equally distributed background colors depending on two characters

Tags: algorithm, colors

I am currently creating a script to map users initials to a background color with the aim to automatically create avatars, if they don't have set one by themselves. Afterwards, the white initials should be on a squared avatar with a background color depending on both characters.

I would like to fulfil the following criteria:

- Two ordered characters always return the same color
- The colors are (nearly) equally distributed over the color space, depending on the 26 letters

I assume that the users initials are equally distributed.

My simple approach is a linear mapping between the 676 (26^2) letter combinations to the 16777216 (256^3) color combinations in RGB space. But it's probably not the best solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: You might get better tips from http://ux.stackexchange.com/, this is more a programing related site and I feel a UX designer would have more to say.

Comment: thanks for the hint, but it's probably more an algorithm question than it is related to user experience (although it is for a good ux, as nearly everything :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RGB space is highly "perceptually non-uniform".  This means that Euclidean distance between two RGB colors is a terrible indicator of how different they will appear to people.  A simple example is that our eyes are much more sensitive to green than blue, so it takes a big difference in the blue RGB color index for us to see a difference in comparison to green.

So you should look into mapping your 26^2 points into a unform 3d grid in a perceptually uniform space.  There are many choices because no one agrees on exactly what perceptual uniformity is; after all, it's a biological/perceptual characteristic, not precise.

But look at CIE Lab space and CIE Luv.  Either of these is certainly close enough to uniform for your purposes: better than RGB by a factor of 20 or more.

There's lots of good information on the Web about conversion from these spaces to RGB.

One place to take care: Not all of the CIE Lab space-specified colors can actually be rendered by a computer monitor: physics of light emission restricts what is possible. (See for example [the Wikepedia page on Lab color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space).  So you should restrict the uniform grid to parts of the Lab/Luv space that correspond to colors a monitor can actually produce.  Simplest is to pick a set of axis-aligned boxes that fill most of the space and fill them with a uniform grid that totals 26^2 points across all boxes.  Count the grid points in each box.  Use the relative sizes to split the 26^2 initial space points among them evenly.  Then map each initial space point in a box to a Lab space grid point with integer arithmetic much as you are already doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Lab and Luv spaces also have the advantage that the colors are only dependent on two parameters: Therefore, mapping first character to u and second character to v seems to be suitable and sufficiently random for this task (while luminance can be fixed)

Comment: @blacklwhite  Great.   However I'm not sure you want to ignore L completely.  Gray is white with decreased L.  Pink->Red. Etc.   But whatever works...

Comment: You are right, it's perfect for my use case, but it is not the answer for my question :)